# Crear columna con número de la semana a partir de un datetime type [Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

necesito crear una columna "week" en un dataframe donde a partir de una columna "Date" aparezca la semana del año. Sin embargo me arroja un error:

```
data["departure_date"].head()
0    2022-02-21
1    2021-10-07
2    2021-12-04
3    2022-01-24
4    2021-11-16
Name: departure_date, dtype: object
```

Ahora realizo el cambio a datetime:

```
data['departure_date']= pd.to_datetime(data['departure_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d', errors = 'coerce')
```

Procedo a crear la columna 'week' ya nombrada.

```
data["week"] = data['departure_date'].dt.week
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Pero obtengo el error `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

He visto otras soluciones pero no me resultan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**crear un dataframe con el numero de la semana** para después unirlo:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *

data['departure_date']= pd.to_datetime(data['departure_date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d', errors = 'coerce')

weeks=[]

for i in data['departure_date']:
    weeks.append(i.strftime("%U"))
weeksdata=pd.DataFrame(weeks)

weeksdata.head()

salida:
    0
0   08
1   40
2   48
3   04
4   46
```